# How to change the threshold on decision tree classifier model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Is it possible to change the threshold of a decisiontreeclassifier? I'm studying the precision/recall trade-off and want to change the threshold to favor recall. I'm studying the hand's on ML, but there it uses the SGDClassifier, at some point it uses the `cross_val_predict()` with the method="decision_function" attribute, but this does not exist for the decisiontreeclassifier. I'm using a pipeline and a cross-validation.
My study is with this dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/imnikhilanand/heart-attack-prediction

```
features = df_heart.drop(['output'], axis=1).copy()
labels = df_heart.output

#split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(features, labels,
                                train_size=0.7,
                                random_state=42,
                                stratify=features["sex"]
                               )
# categorical features
cat = ['sex', 'tipo_de_dor', 'ang_indz_exerc', 'num_vasos', 'acuc_sang_jejum', 'eletrc_desc', 'pico_ST_exerc', 'talassemia']

# treatment of categorical variables
t = [('cat', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), cat)]

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=t, remainder='passthrough')

#pipeline
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                       ('clf', DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_leaf=8, random_state=42),)
                       ]
                )

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

valid_cruz_strat = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=14, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(pipe['clf'], X_train, y_train, cv=valid_cruz_strat)

conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_train, y_train_pred)


ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=conf_mat, 
                       display_labels=pipe['clf'].classes_).plot()
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

[image: confusion matrix]

```
threshold = 0 #this is only for support the graph
idx = (thresholds >= threshold).argmax()  # first index ≥ threshold

plt.plot(thresholds, precisions[:-1], 'b--', label = 'Precisão')
plt.plot(thresholds, recalls[:-1], 'g-', label = 'Recall')
plt.vlines(threshold, 0, 1.0, "k", "dotted", label="threshold")
plt.title('Precisão x Recall', fontsize = 14)

plt.plot(thresholds[idx], precisions[idx], "bo")
plt.plot(thresholds[idx], recalls[idx], "go")
plt.axis([-.5, 1.5, 0, 1.1])
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Threshold")
plt.legend(loc="lower left")

plt.show()
```

[image: Precision/Recall - threshold]

```
valid_cruz_strat = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=14, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

y_score = cross_val_predict(pipe['clf'], X_train, y_train, cv=valid_cruz_strat)

precisions, recalls, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_train, y_score)

threshold = 0.75 #this is only for support the graph
idx = (thresholds >= threshold).argmax() 

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))  

plt.plot(recalls, precisions, linewidth=2, label="Precision/Recall curve")

plt.plot([recalls[idx], recalls[idx]], [0., precisions[idx]], "k:")
plt.plot([0.0, recalls[idx]], [precisions[idx], precisions[idx]], "k:")
plt.plot([recalls[idx]], [precisions[idx]], "ko",
         label="Point at threshold "+str(threshold))

plt.xlabel("Recall")
plt.ylabel("Precision")
plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc="lower left")

plt.show()
```

[image: Precision x Recall]

When I check the arrays generated by the `precision_recall_curve()` function I see that it only contains 3 elements. Is this correct behavior? When I do the `cross_val_predict()` function for an SGDClassifier, for example, as it is in the book, without the method='decision_function' attribute and I use the output in `precision_recall_curve()` and it generates arrays with 3 elements and if I use the method='decision_function ' it generates arrays with several elements.

My main question is how to choose the threshold for the DecisionTreeClassifier, and if there is a way to generate the Precision x Recall curve with several points, I only manage with these three points and I am not able to assimilate how to improve the recall.

Move the threshold to improve recall, and understand how to do it with Decision tree classifier

Comment: This _could_ be a pretty good question, except that you haven't made {x,y}_train [available](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to us. Also, please fix up the image legend.

Comment: Start with threshold of zero, and gradually increase it to the current .75 setting. That way `idx` starts with all points plotted, and you gradually discard more and more of them. Your complaint essentially is that "too many are discarded" right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic usually falls under the name "*model calibration*." `scikit-learn` supports a few kinds of [probability calibration](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) which could be informative to read about as well.

One way to "change the threshold" in a `DecisionTreeClassifier` would involve invoking `.predict_proba(X)` and observing a metric(s) over possible thresholds:

```py
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10000, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

prob_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

thresholds = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, step=0.01)
recall_scores = [recall_score(y_test, prob_pred > t) for t in thresholds]
precis_scores = [precision_score(y_test, prob_pred > t) for t in thresholds]
```

Now we have a set of thresholds between `0.0` and `1.0`, and we've computed precision and recall over each threshold (**Side note**: this problem is less-well-defined for multilabel or multiclass prediction—usually these metrics are averaged over each class or similar).

Then we'll plot:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(thresholds, recall_scores, label="Recall @ t")
ax.plot(thresholds, precis_scores, label="Precision @ t")
ax.axvline(0.5, c="gray", linestyle="--", label="Default Threshold")
ax.set_xlabel("Threshold")
ax.set_ylabel("Metric @ Threshold")
ax.set_box_aspect(1)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Which results in a figure like this:

[image: A line plot showing thresholds from 0 to 1 on the x axis and recall on the y axis. The line is parabolic, with high recall for low thresholds and low recall for high thresholds.]

This shows us that the default threshold used by `.predict()` at `0.5` may not be the best in all circumstances. In fact, there are a range of thresholds where precision and recall are *fairly* close, but favors one over the other. In this case: lowering the threshold slightly will tend to favor recall, while increasing the threshold will tend to favor precision.

In practice: the threshold appropriate for the problem comes down to domain knowledge since there's always a trade-off between precision and recall.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander. But I have two points. 1. How to set the threshold for the rest of the analysis?? 2. Can I use the ```cross_val_predict()``` like you use ```clf.predict_proba()``` ?

Comment: (1) Once you've decided which threshold to use (e.g. `t = 0.3`), you can post-process using `pred = clf.predict_proba(X) > t`.

Comment: (2) Maybe. You can set `cross_val_predict(method='predict_proba')`, but I might not be understanding what you mean. This answer requires *visually inspecting* the results, so you may need to define a metric representing what you care about to avoid visual inspection in each CV fold. It might be possible with [`cross_val_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html), so long as you can define the `scoring` parameter for your metric.

Comment: I need high recall, so I did: ```cross_val_score()``` with some k's and I choose the k with higher recall. Then I did: ```y_train_pred_prob = cross_val_predict(pipe['clf'], X_train, y_train, cv=valid_cruz_strat, method='predict_proba')[:,1]``` 

```fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_train, y_train_pred_prob)```. So, the next step is change the threshold to increase the recall and roc_auc_score. 
To move across the Threshold I'll use the method that you teach me above